# What is the fastest way to record real-time data in python with least memory loss

Tags: python, database, logging, save, bigdata

In every step of a loop I have some data which I want to be saved in the end in my hard disk.

One way:

```
list = []
for i in range(1e10):
    list.append(numpy_array_i)

pickle.dump(list, open(self.save_path, "wb"), protocol=4)
```

But I worry: 1_I ran out of memory for because of the list 2_If something crashes all data will be lost.
Because of this I have also thought of a way to save data in real time such as:

```
file = make_new_csv_or_xlsx_file()
for i in range(1e10):
    file.write_in_a_new_line(numpy_array_i)
```

For this also I worry it may not be so fast and am not sure what the best tools might be. But probably openpyxl is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to `redis` is pretty fast. And you may read from `redis` in second process and write to disk

Comment: I'm not sure if Redis is a good choice if memory usage is mentioned as a concern...

Comment: Redis flushes memory to disk if needed

Comment: @Belegnar Can you give me some clues for how I can use redis efficiently? for each step I get a 1 dimensional np.array at the moment

Comment: From my point of view you should use redis `set` or `sorted set`, decision depends. Then you should run two threads: one adds serialized element to the set, other pops from the set and processes records in the way you need. This links are useful
redis manual https://redis.io/commands#set
python redis lib https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis

Answer (score 0):

I'd try SQLite, as it provides permanent storage on disk (-> no data loss), and yet it's faster than writing into a file as shown in your question and provides easier data lookup in case you'd have incomplete data from previous run.

Tweaking `JOURNAL_MODE` can increase the performance further: https://blog.devart.com/increasing-sqlite-performance.html