# How to continuously collect data and save to a file every 5 second

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, sensors

I am collecting data from a sensor with 200ms sampling rate. I need to collect and take average of its signal strength which can be retrieved from the received data. Currently I can collect and save data every minute. However, I need to shorten the time so that I can get more real-time average value.
Here is what my code look like.

```
count = 0
record = []

while (str(datetime.datetime.now().second)!="59"):
    ser_bytes = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')[:-1].rstrip() # Read the newest output
    if ser_bytes:
        arr = ser_bytes.split(':')
        i=0
        db=[]
        with open("test_data.csv","a") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
            writer.writerow([ser_bytes])



ser_bytes = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')[:-1].rstrip() # Read the newest output
if ser_bytes:
    arr = ser_bytes.split(':')
    i=0
    db=[]
    with open("test_data.csv","a") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
        writer.writerow([ser_bytes])

start_time = str(datetime.datetime.now().hour) + "_" + str(datetime.datetime.now().minute) + "_" + str(datetime.datetime.now().second)

with open(pi_dir1+r_ID+start_time+".csv","w") as correct:                  
    writer = csv.writer(correct, dialect = 'excel')
    with open('test_data.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as mycsv:
        reader = csv.reader((line.replace('\x00','') for line in mycsv))
        try:
            for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                writer.writerow(row)
        except csv.Error:
            print(r_ID+' csv choked on line %s' % (i+1))
            raise
os.remove("test_data.csv")
soc.sendall(str(r_ID).encode("utf8")) 
time.sleep(5)
```

Here is what inside the created csv data which is saved using the recording time information as its file name (e.g. 12_12_59)
[Collected data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfPkT.jpg)

Then, I want to shorted the duration from 1 minute long into 5 seconds. First, I tried to reduce into 15 seconds, but it seems that I couldn't implement time.sleep(15). Because when I do that, it will only capture one line without continuously record data as the sampling rate.

```
ser_bytes = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')[:-1].rstrip() # Read the newest output
if ser_bytes:
    arr = ser_bytes.split(':')
    i=0
    db=[]
    with open("test_data.csv","a") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
        writer.writerow([ser_bytes])

start_time = str(datetime.datetime.now().hour) + "_" + str(datetime.datetime.now().minute) + "_" + str(datetime.datetime.now().second)

with open(pi_dir1+r_ID+start_time+".csv","w") as correct:                  
    writer = csv.writer(correct, dialect = 'excel')
    with open('test_data.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as mycsv:
        reader = csv.reader((line.replace('\x00','') for line in mycsv))
        try:
            for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                writer.writerow(row)
        except csv.Error:
            print(r_ID+' csv choked on line %s' % (i+1))
            raise
os.remove("test_data.csv")
soc.sendall(str(r_ID).encode("utf8")) 
time.sleep(15)
```

Here's what it would appear when I use time.sleep(15)
[captured data with time.sleep(15)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rcvq.jpg)

Moreover, to process the program, the time was delayed so my data was not recorded in exact duration that I want. The created file received by the server looks like this: [delayed process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLu5g.jpg)

Please kindly help me by giving suggestion in solving this problem. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684887/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-record-real-time-data-in-python-with-least-memory-los

Comment: i can help you with best way to set scheduled automated task using **time** and **schedule** modules like this example https://www.github.com/IT-Support-L2/Automated-Task-with-schedule-and-subprocess-Python-modules/tree/master/automated_task.py

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in table format, then I suggest that you think in terms of database tables. There might me a little of a learning curve initially, but try using something simple like **SQLite**, or any other DB framework of your choice.
Then you can have either a shorter sleep time or multiple processes running and fetching data from overlapping timeframes.
Databases are fast, and later you can export your readings from DB table to CSV, or any other format you prefer.

Comment: The raw data is actually a line that should be parsed to catch a certain parameter in each line. The parsing is not processed on client side which in charge of reads line by line of information, writes in a CSV format every certain period, and sends it to the server.